# How to change an option's value for a specific object?

Tags: options

I have a `Graph` object `x` such that

```
GraphLayout /. AbsoluteOptions[x]
```

evaluates to `Automatic`.

I want generate an object `y` from `x` such that

```
GraphLayout /. AbsoluteOptions[y]
```

evaluates to the string `"RadialEmbedding"`.

In principle, I imagine that `y` could be generated from `x` in a way that leaves `x` unchanged.  Alternatively, `y` could be an "in-place mutation" of `x`.  I'm interested in both approaches.  (If "in-place mutation" is the only convenient way to produce the desired `y`, then I'd like to know how to "clone" `x`, so that I can mutate the clone and leave `x` unaffected.)

PS: I spent a huge amount of time poring over the *Mathematica* documentation in search for the answer to this question, obviously without any success.  I'd be curious to know what keywords I could have used in my search to find the answer.

Comment: It's no wonder you couldn't find it easily. Graph functionality is a muddy terrain. There are a few superimposed ways to define graphs and the docs aren't clear at all.

Comment: Read carefully [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1028/1356) instead of rollingback.

Comment: @belisarius: actually, I approached the question generally, from the standpoint of modifying an arbitrary option in an arbitrary object.  I thought that this would be an easy-to-find topic.  I was wrong.

Comment: @kjo Graphs are _very_ particular objects!

Comment: @belisarius: Thanks for the tip; I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both:

Generating a second Graph:

```
x = PathGraph[Range[20]];
GraphLayout /. AbsoluteOptions[x]
y = SetProperty[x, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"];
GraphLayout /. AbsoluteOptions[y]

(*
Automatic

"RadialEmbedding"

*)
```

Modifying the property:

```
PropertyValue[x, GraphLayout] = "RadialEmbedding";
GraphLayout /. AbsoluteOptions[x]

(*
"RadialEmbedding"
*)
```